# Cannot send Authorization header to Node 11 / Express 4 server using Angular 7

Tags: node.js, angular, express, jwt

I cannot send the **Authorization** header via a GET **request** from my angular front to my node back, that are on the same VPS.

To make the request from **angular** I use

```
return this.httpClient.get<ApiResponse>(ApiClientService.apiAddress + ApiClientService.secureRoute + '/posts');
```

And use this http interceptor from JwtModule that sets the authorization header, in app.module.ts

```
  imports: [
    ...,
    JwtModule.forRoot({
      config: {
        tokenGetter,
        whitelistedDomains: [ApiClientService.apiAddress, 'vps.ip.address:VPS_FRONT_PORT', 'localhost:BACK_PORT', 'localhost:FRONT_PORT'], //todo clean
      }
    }),
```

When I look the request in chromium inspector on the front I see

```
GET /secure/posts HTTP/1.1
Host: vps.ip.address:VPS_BACK_PORT
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: vps.ip.address:VPS_FRONT_PORT
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/73.0.3683.86 Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36
Referer: vps.ip.address:VPS_FRONT_PORT/posts
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8
```

We notice that the Authorization header is **missing**.

---

The problem *does not come from the interceptor* IMO, as

- When making the **same request**, but to google.com, I see the Authorization header in the chrome inspector
- When adding the headers **manually**, without an interceptor, I have the same problem

Which makes me think that the problem comes from the **CORS**/preflight request configuration of my **node** server. *api.config.js*

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*, localhost, localhost:FRONT_PORT, vps.ip.address:VPS_FRONT_PORT'); //todo change *
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
})
```

...

```
const secureApi = express.Router();
app.use('/secure', secureApi);
secureApi.use(checkToken);
ProblemRoute.init(secureApi);
PostRoute.init(secureApi);
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.status(500).send('Something broke!');
});
const ApiConfig = {
    app: app
};

module.exports = ApiConfig;
```

I **read** the Authorization header on the node server. *secureRoute.js*

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

module.exports = function checkToken(req, res, next) {
    const authHeader = req.headers['authorization'];
    console.log(req.headers);
    if (authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        const token = authHeader.substring(7, authHeader.length);

        if (token) {
            jwt.verify(token, 'my_secret_key', (err, decode) => {
                if (err) {
                    res.status(400).json({
                        "message": "Invalid token",
                    });
                } else {
                    next();
                }
            })
        } else {
            res.status(400).json({
                "message": "Token must be provided in header for endpoint access",
            });
        }
    } else {
        res.status(400).json({
            "message": "Token must be provided in header for endpoint access",
        });
    }
};
```

Which of course causes an **error** because the Authorization header is **missing** from the angular front request.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined
>       at checkToken (/home/me/project/node-project/config/secureRoute.js:6:20)

When I make a similar request with **postman** it *works correctly*, this is the postman developer console log

> GET
>   /snap/postman/81/usr/share/Postman/resources/app/html/vps.ip.address:BACK_PORT/secure/posts
>   Content-Type: application/json cache-control: no-cache Postman-Token:
>   10a5caf7-711e-4c39-9437-58dd825ca05f Authorization: Bearer
>   eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJtYWlsIjoicGF1bEBiZWxsb2Mub3ZoIiwiaWF0IjoxNTU1ODgzMjgxLCJleHAiOjE1NTU5Njk2ODF9.s6z5hBLJWEdlDgzw9E9ePiLWj9hqmd39RF68FNRlgLk
>   User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.6.0 Accept: */* Host: vps.ip.address:BACK_PORT
>   accept-encoding: gzip, deflate

And the node server reads the request / headers and answers 200 and content, as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the error, I think, comes from the interceptor I misconfigured. I included the 'http://' part in the whitelisted domain, which makes it act incorrectly I believe.

I also started using the cors npm package, but I don't think this was the fix.